# My project has disappeared from iMovie -- can you help me get it back?

Tags: mac, video, imovie

I have been working on a project on iMovie and yesterday I opened iMovie to continue working on it but I can't find it.

It says I have two projects but it only shows me one project and I am freaking out because I am suppose to show this video at my graduation for my whole school and every things gone but I don't know where it went.

Can you please help me find out where it went and get it back?

Comment: [I made a chat room for you](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14836/discussion-with-buscar-and-user79432). Please use it to discuss your problem and not the comment feature of the site. Thanks.

Comment: @Buscar웃 i did what you said i am suppose to do but i didn't find it all it says in the movie folder is imovie library,imovie theater and motion templates

Comment: This might be stupid but do you have 2 iMovie applications. Look under applications.

Comment: @user79432 you *should* be able to join that [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14836/discussion-with-buscar-and-user79432) now. Sorry that took so long to sort out.

Answer (score 1):

Open Finder, on the far left of your Dock, then click "Applications" on the sidebar, then double-click "Utilities", then "Terminal". In the window that shows up, paste this in:

```
term="$(osascript -e 'text returned of (display dialog "What do you want to find?" default answer "rcproject")')"; d=0; for x in $(find ~ -iregex ".*$term.*" | sed 's/ /\ /g'); do let d++; osascript -e 'on run argv' -e 'tell app "Finder" to reveal (POSIX file (item 1 of argv) as string)' -e end "$x" >/dev/null; if [[ d -gt 10 ]]; then echo "Press Control-C to quit."; fi done; if [[ $d -ne 0 ]]; then open -a Finder; else v="$(osascript -e 'button returned of (display dialog "No files were found. Try again looking everywhere?")')"; if [[ $v = OK ]]; then for x in $(find / -iregex ".*$term.*" 2>/dev/null | sed 's/ /\ /g'); do let d++; osascript -e 'on run argv' -e 'tell app "Finder" to reveal (POSIX file (item 1 of argv) as string)' -e end "$x" >/dev/null; done; open -a Finder; fi; fi; open ~/Movies/ #END
```

<sup>If you're having trouble selecting it all, double-click the first word ("term"), then scroll all the way to the right, then hold shift and click on where it says "END".</sup>

Press <kbd>return ↩</kbd> if another window doesn't show up.

Then, the window should ask what you want to find. Leave what's in there at first, because `rcproject` should match all iMovie files. If it says it couldn't find any files, click OK. If it *still* couldn't find any files (it might take a long time to look), then repeat the above with something else (like Klass 6B-9B). I doubt you will find anything else, unfortunately.

A Finder window will pop up with your Movies folder. If any others show up behind it, try dragging those things (only `.rcproject`s will work for this) into the iMovie Projects folder in that window.

I don't know where it says you have two projects, but if this doesn't work, it's possible that the file got corrupted somehow…

Answer (score 0):

This is truly SPF event.

OK, Using Finder look in this folders for your file.

[image: Klass 6B-9B]

To modify the side bar click on Finder-> preferences and then select Movie Folder like this

[image: finder]

This could be also a case of mistaken identity.

For example I have 2 versions of the iMovie application. the version 9 and the version 10.

See if you have that as well, since the movies/projects are not saved in same location.

Comment: "SPF event" -- what's that?

Answer (score 0):

I just found my project! imovie quit unexpectedly and then I opened it back up, selected "all projects" in the left column and when I clicked on the thumbnail for the video i got back to the editing screen with all my edits! SOOOOO happy right now, hope this works for someone else too!! xo Krissy

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this after a Big Sur 11.2.1 update with iMovie 10.2.2.  After trying a number of different things, the only thing that solved it for me was resetting iMovie by deleting the preferences as described at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203922